# Surprising function signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell newbie, please forgive me for asking this which might be obvious, but I am surprised by this:

```
len2 :: [a] -> Int
len2 xx = if xx == [] then 0 else 1 + (len2 (tail xx))
```

gives me:

```
No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’
Possible fix:
  add (Eq a) to the context of
    the type signature for len2 :: [a] -> Int
In the expression: xx == []
```

I am surprised because I thought Haskell could tell whether a list was `[]` or not without looking at any element (in C++, I would see that the list has size 0 and leave it at that, for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `(==)` in this case is `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`. Hopefully you agree that before you see any arguments the `Eq a` constraint makes sense: if you want to check two *arbitrary* lists are equal, you have to know how to check if elements are equal. You might wish that once you applied `(==)` to the concrete argument `[]` that the `Eq a` constraint wasn't needed, but this is actually quite a subtle thing to notice. Perhaps partial evaluation would be able to produce a function that didn't have the constraint. But extant implementations do not try to do this analysis; they keep the conservative type `Eq a => [a] -> Bool` which has discharged an `[a]` argument but not the `Eq a` constraint.

Some options:

1. Use `null :: [a] -> Bool` instead of `(==[])`.

   ```
   len2 xx = if null xx then ... else ...
   ```
2. Pattern match, thus:

   ```
   len2 []     = ...
   len2 (x:xs) = ...
   ```

   As a bonus, this way you can avoid calling the nasty `tail` function.

I would say choice (2) is significantly more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks - I understand. I guess I was expecting that Haskell would look inside the [] to realize it was just the empty list, but doing that would probably be a very specific optimization that might not be worthwhile in general.